# Generate row grouping recursively in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am having trouble with a function to generate a table with multiple levels of row groupings in JavaScript.

The recursive function is called drawGrouping and it is defined as:

```
this.drawGrouping = function(tbody, listOfObjects, groupings, index) {
  //check if there are grouping levels remaining
    if (index < groupings.length) {

        var g = groupings[index];

        var pvList = database.getValuesForProperty(g);

        for (var i = 0; i < pvList.length; i++) {
            var val = pvList[i];

               //creates a grouping <tr> row
            var row = this.generateGroupingRow(g, val, index+1);
            tbody.append(row);

               //returns a filtered list of objects that belong under this grouping
            var objs = database.filter(listOfObjects, g, '==', val);

               //call the function again, supplying the filtered list
               //and a new index
            this.drawGrouping(tbody, objs, groupings, index++);
        }

    } else {
        //exits the recursion and prints the regular table rows
        for (var i = 0; i < listOfObjects.length; i++) {
            tbody.append(this.generateTableRow(listOfObjects[i]));
        }

    }
}
```

Then I kick off the function with:

```
this.drawGrouping(tableBodyTag, listOfObjects, listOfGroupNames, 0);
```

The problem is that the first level of grouping works fine, but subsequent levels will only appear for the first section. I believe it is a problem with variable scope but I am not sure.

Here is an image of what the output looks like with some junk data. The table has been grouped by 'Owner First Name' and then by 'Fiscal Period' and for some reason the latter grouping only appears one time. [image: problem]

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using recursion instead of a plain loop? The function doesn't return anything, and the return value isn't assigned anywhere if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing your internal `index` counter, but not passing the incremented version down in recursive calls. If I'm following your logic, you mean to say:

```
this.drawGrouping(tbody, objs, groupings, index + 1);
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks for the help!